# Custom singly linklist method iteration method

Tags: java, linked-list

Hey I am a beginner at java im trying to implement a linklist. I was given this problem to experiment on. First is the problem and below is the given class will be at the bottom. An extension problem was if the size method was called from the middle of the link list, how would i get the correct size.

```
* Method to return the size of the word.
     * 
     * @return the size of the word.
     */
    public int size() {
        Letter current = start;
        int count =0;
        while(current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return count;


    }
```

this is the link list class

```
 /*
 * The customNode class is the nodes of 
 */
public class customNode {
    
    // the customNode 
    public char letter;
    // the customNode's score
    public int score;
    // the next customNode in the list
    public customNode next;
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param customNode - the customNode  
     * @param score  - the score of the customNode
     */
    public customNode(char customNode, int score) {
        this.letter = customNode;
        this.score = score;
        this.next = null;
    }
        
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param customNode - the customNode  
     * @param score  - the score of the customNode
     * @param next   - the next customNode in the list
     */
    public customNode(char customNode, int score, customNode next) {
        this.letter = customNode;
        this.score = score;
        this.next = next;
        
    }
        
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.letter + "," + this.score + ")";
    }
    
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    
    public char getcustomNode() {
        return letter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what is the question?

Comment: What is the problem?  Does it not give you the expected answer?  Or are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: The question is to try to return the size of the word but in one of the test cases that was provided to me it calls it from the middle  of the node ie idx 6. My current understanding for how return size is from the beginning but I am unsure as to how to call it from anywhere of the linked list.

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing to understand as I am having issues completely understanding this concept.

Comment: @hugh - unless this is a circular single linked list, you can't compute the size from other than the beginning of the list. There is no information in the question on what variable is used to keep track of the beginning of the list and if the list is a circular list or not.